# How to display months in x axis labels in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

[image]**PROBLEM**
I have data coming for x axis as *xAxisLabel* ['Jul 16', 'Oct 16', 'Jan 17', 'May 17', 'Jul 17', 'Oct 17', 'Jan 18', 'Apr 18','Aug 20','Sep 20'] whose length may vary. I have to display only 8 labels on the x-axis whatever the length of data may be i.e skip interval will be decided by dividing length of data by 8.
**Solutions TRIED**
I tried using *tickPositioner* to pass only 8 dates. But somehow, it is not getting displayed.

```
xAxis: {
        tickPositioner: function() {
        let dataDisplay=[]
        let xAxisLabel=['Jul 16', 'Oct 16', 'Jan 17', 'May 17', 'Jul 17', 'Oct 17', 'Jan 18', 'Apr 
        18','Aug 20','Sep 20'];
        let steps = xAxisLabel.length/8
        for(let i=0,k=0;k<8;i+=steps,k++){

            dataDisplay[k] = xAxisLabel[i]

        }
        return dataDisplay;
    },
        labels:{
            enabled:true,
            formatter: function(){
                   return this.value;
                }
                },

            },
```

Can anyone help in achieving the desired result?
Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/harshita_97/sd3trebz/20/

Comment: check out this example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/ - you should parse your strings as real dates and then set up your data as a 2D array like ``[ [date, val], [date, val],...]``

Comment: Hi @Harshita, How do you want to select these eight labels?

Comment: these 8 labels are to be selected from the data starting from first date and then by deciding skip value i.e dividing total dates received by 8 and skipping through that interval.

Comment: @Harshita do you have any questions? does my answer solve your problem? If so please consider to up-vote and mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: See updated screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/axuLJ.png taken from my updated answer below and here: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/6p1nk73y/20/

Answer (score 2):

I have a full example here (any questions let me know).

https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/6p1nk73y/14/

Also, here in a Stack Overflow Snippet:

```js
let xAxisLabel=['Jul 16', 'Oct 16', 'Jan 17', 'May 17', 'Jul 17', 'Oct 17', 'Jan 18', 'Apr 18','Aug 20','Sep 20', 'Oct 20', 'Dec 20'];
let yAxisData = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

//const newDate = new Date('Jul 1 16'); //test it parses data correctly
const myData = xAxisLabel.map((child,index) => {
 const modString = child.replace(/ /, " 1 ");
  const newDate = new Date(modString);
  const month = newDate.getMonth();
  const year = newDate.getFullYear();
  return [Date.UTC(year, month, 1),yAxisData[index]]
});

//console.log(myData)
        
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Example data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // do display the year
            month: '%b %y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        /*tickInterval: 1*/
        tickPixelInterval: 100
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Some Example Values'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: "my Example Data",
        data: myData     
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

Output:

[image]

Important is to parse your strings to real dates and then add them in the data as a 2D array.

this is done with the `.map()`, essentially zipping the two arrays together:

```js
let xAxisLabel=['Jul 16', 'Oct 16', 'Jan 17', 'May 17', 'Jul 17', 'Oct 17', 'Jan 18', 'Apr 18','Aug 20','Sep 20', 'Oct 20', 'Dec 20'];
let yAxisData = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

//const newDate = new Date('Jul 1 16'); //test it parses data correctly
const myData = xAxisLabel.map((child,index) => {
    const modString = child.replace(/ /, " 1 ");
    const newDate = new Date(modString);
    const month = newDate.getMonth();
    const year = newDate.getFullYear();
    return [Date.UTC(year, month, 1),yAxisData[index]]
});
```

Essentially giving this data structure:

```
[
  [1467331200000, 29.9]
  [1475280000000, 71.5]
  [1483228800000, 106.4]
  [1493596800000, 129.2]
  [1498867200000, 144]
  [1506816000000, 176]
  [1514764800000, 135.6]
  [1522540800000, 148.5]
  [1596240000000, 216.4]
  [1598918400000, 194.1]
  [1601510400000, 95.6]
  [1606780800000, 54.4]
]
```

**Also to modify the ticks:**

And to modify the ticks, you can modify like this (with `tickPixelInterval: 60` etc.):

```js
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%b',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        /* tickInterval: 1 */
        tickPixelInterval: 60
    },
```

Then we get:

[image]

Or with `tickPixelInterval: 20` we get:

[image]

To modify the ticks further you can try this:

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // do display the year
            month: '%b %y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        /*tickInterval: 1*/
        tickPixelInterval: 10
    }
```

Then the output also includes the year in the month view like so:

[image]

Example:

```js
let xAxisLabel=['Jul 16', 'Oct 16', 'Jan 17', 'May 17', 'Jul 17', 'Oct 17', 'Jan 18', 'Apr 18','Aug 20','Sep 20', 'Oct 20', 'Dec 20'];
let yAxisData = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

//const newDate = new Date('Jul 1 16'); //test it parses data correctly
const myData = xAxisLabel.map((child,index) => {
 const modString = child.replace(/ /, " 1 ");
  const newDate = new Date(modString);
  const month = newDate.getMonth();
  const year = newDate.getFullYear();
  return [Date.UTC(year, month, 1),yAxisData[index]]
});

//console.log(myData)
        
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Example data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // do display the year
            month: '%b %y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        /*tickInterval: 1*/
        tickPixelInterval: 10
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Some Example Values'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: "my Example Data",
        data: myData     
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

or demo in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/6p1nk73y/20/

Comment: +1 for the explanation. The data that i am receiving as a series is a separate data and then there is another not included in the series data array which is giving me month and the year. Can it not be done by not combining the series data with x axis.

Comment: Thanks. Every data point (y-value), needs a corresponding x-value, right? I don't know why you would want to keep them separate? Your dates are also not regularly spaced so how would you know where to plot your points without making this joining/connection between x and y? Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly and what benefit it would bring? If your datapoints were always spaced apart by say 1 month then we could do it without explicitly setting x. (i.e. just specifying the start date and the data spacing).

Comment: My requirement is to display months as well, in this example I am not able to show months.The format to display is for example Jan 18

Comment: Can you include (in your question) a screenshot or a sketch or something of your desired output please?

Comment: I have added a photo. That is how the x axis should be represented.

Comment: The spacing between the x-axis data labels is not consistent? Like sometimes it’s 3 months sometimes it’s 1 year? Sounds like a categorical x-axis then (not advisable for time series data as it’s not an accurate representation)

Comment: Updated my answer.